# Jquery Max character with character count for input and textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got this working ok, I just think that it can be improved and reduce the amount of code. If anybody could help that would be brilliant.

```
// Max Length Input
$('input[maxlength]').each(function() {         
    var maxCharLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");  

    if(maxCharLength < 0 || maxCharLength > 5000){
    } else {
        var charLength = $(this).val().length;
        $(this).after("<span class='charCount clearBoth' id='charCount_"+$(this).attr("name").replace(".","_")+"'> " + charLength + " of " + maxCharLength + " characters used</span>");        
        $(this).keyup(function() {              
            var charLength = $(this).val().length;              
            $(this).next("span").html(charLength + ' of ' + maxCharLength + ' characters used');

            if(charLength == maxCharLength ) {
                $(this).next("span").html('<strong> Maximum of ' + maxCharLength + ' characters used.</strong>');
                $(this).next("span").addClass("red");
            } else { $(this).next("span").removeClass("red"); }
        });
    }
});

// Max Length textarea
$('textarea[maxlength]').each(function() {          
    var maxCharLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");  

    if(maxCharLength < 0 || maxCharLength > 5000){
    } else {
        var charLength = $(this).val().length;
        $(this).after("<span class='charCount clearBoth'> " + charLength + " of " + maxCharLength + " characters used</span>");

            $('textarea[maxlength]').keyup(function(){

                var limit = parseInt($(this).attr('maxlength'));
                var text = $(this).val();
                var chars = text.length;

                $(this).next("span").html(chars + ' of ' + limit + ' characters used');

                if(chars > limit){
                    var new_text = text.substr(0, limit);
                    $(this).val(new_text);

                    $(this).next("span").html('<strong> Maximum of ' + limit + ' characters used.</strong>');
                    $(this).next("span").addClass("red");
                } else { $(this).find("span").removeClass("red"); }
            });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things I would suggest:
1. Replace you numbers with constants and revert the condition to get rid of 'else':

```
var minTextLength = 0;
var maxTextLength = 5000;
if (maxCharLength >= minTextLength || maxCharLength <= maxTextLength){
      //Your code...
    }
```

2. Move the block of code:

```
$(this).next("span").html('<strong> Maximum of ' + maxCharLength + ' characters used.</strong>');
            $(this).next("span").addClass("red");
        } else { $(this).next("span").removeClass("red"); }
```

To a separate function.

And there are a couple of things that confuse me:
1. In 'Max Length textarea' you have:

```
$('textarea[maxlength]').keyup()
```

Is it correct? Becasue it means that you'll add a lot of handlers to all your textarea[maxlength].

2
. In your 'Max Length Input' you have:

```
if(charLength == maxCharLength )
```

Maybe it could be replaced with:

```
if(charLength > maxCharLength )
```

Depending on the answers to these questions, maybe it'll be possible to move the keyup  handler to a separate function. And maybe even the whole code from both 'Max Length textarea' and 'Max Length Input'.